# What is the regular expression of remove the line in text file

Tags: c#, regex

this is my line in text file. I want to remove this line from my text file using regular expression.

```
---------- RECOMMENDATION 1 OF 3 IN GROUP 1 (USD 168.90)----------
```

I am trying this code but it's give error.

```
       StreamReader sreader = File.OpenText(@"C:\FareSearchRegex.txt");
       string line;
       while ((line = sreader.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
  var pattern = "---------- RECOMMENDATION 1 OF 3 IN GROUP 1 \(USD 168.90\)----------";

       var result = Regex.Replace(sreader,pattern," ");
        }
```

Comment: That particular line ? Or lines *like* that ? What's common and what differs between these and other lines ?

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: Regular expressions are used to match patterns, not exact strings. Are there more lines like that one which you'd like removed? If not, regular expressions shouldn't be your go-to tool.

Comment: asp.net c# and visual studio 2010.

Comment: Please show some edge cases - a range of lines that match and others that don't, so we can understand what the regex pattern must match and not match

Comment: hey brain, this is line. actually I want to parse my text file plz consider as line.

Comment: any final solution with full source code ?

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions do one thing, and one thing only:

*They match text.*

Everything else (such as removing it, replacing it, you name it) is a functionality offered by a library, not by regular expressions themselves.

The regular expression to *match* your line is remarkably simple:

```
---------- RECOMMENDATION 1 OF 3 IN GROUP 1 \(USD 168\.90\)----------
```

… but how to *remove* it depends on the language / library you are using. Since you are using C#, you can use the [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) method:

```
var pattern = "---------- RECOMMENDATION 1 OF 3 IN GROUP 1 \(USD 168\.90\)----------"
var result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "");
```

But since your pattern is really just a fixed string it’s slightly more efficient and simpler to just use the plain [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method:

```
var line = "---------- RECOMMENDATION 1 OF 3 IN GROUP 1 (USD 168.90)----------";
var result = text.Replace(line, "");
```

Comment: I am using asp.net C#  and visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the exact line, there is no need to use regular expression. Regular expressions, in general, are used to match patterns.
Still if you want to use regular expression for this line, you can proceed with this:

```
---------- RECOMMENDATION 1 OF 3 IN GROUP 1 \(USD 168.90\)----------
```

Do not forget to add `\` before `(` and `)`